# How to Handle backpressure in spring cloud steam reactive

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring5

I am using Spring Cloud to consume a Kafka topic, do some processing and store the result in a Mongo DB. I noticed that if my consumer is slow in processing that the Memory consumption climbs rapidly until bringing the service down.

Further Analysis showed that the Spring cloud uses BUFFER back pressure strategy by default, and hence the buffer fills up and eats away all the memory.

My question is, is there an way in Spring cloud to specify the back pressure strategy (rather than just buffer)? and if not, is there a way to limit/configure the buffer size?